# Create separate location inside nginx to enable req_limit_zone for sepcific file

Tags: nginx, limit, nginx-location, zone, req

I cannot setup `req_limit_zone` for specific file inside `location` since, as I figured it out, the main `location` catches the request and it never comes to the targeted file.
Configuration inside nginx looks like this

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?=$uri&$args;
        }

        location /wordpress/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
        }

        location /wordpress/xmlrpc.php$ {
                limit_req zone=mylimit;
        }
```

The goal is to setup `limit_req_zone` on `xmlrpc.php` file so I can create fail2ban rules to ban people who try to send POST requests.

Comment: You have added a `$` to the end of the URI. Even if you fix the typo, the `location` block needs the code from the `location ~ \.php$` block, which was previously used to process  the request.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for your reply i have made changes and i did some other testing i have placed limit configuration inside /wordpress location and it is catching limits now but still it doesnt catch /wordpress/xmlrpc.php but when i try to hit /wordpress/test.txt the limit conf triggers, dont know why it doesnt work for .php files.